# Move code lines to most left side in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Please see the attached photo. I´m trying to configs my IntelliJ to align the code line to the most left side. Could you please help ?
[image]

Comment: Do you use Distraction Free Mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was like this:

**View --> Appearance --> Exit Distraction Free Mode**

The hint was from @y.bedrov